# Tags com wiki sem perguntas também são apagadas pelo sistema?

Tags: suporte, tags, tag-específica

Eu li em algum lugar que depois de um tempo é feito uma limpeza (não sei se é automatizada) das tags sem perguntas e elas somem (posso ter lido errado me corrija se for o caso).

Gostaria de saber se tags com wiki ou fragmento podem ser deletadas?

O motivo disto é que foi criado uma tag chamada:

- [material-designer](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/material-designer)

Quando vi está tag editei a pergunta vinculada e criei a tag com o termo mais apropriado:

- [material-design](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/material-design)

Adicionei o wiki a ela e reprovei a solicitação de edição da wiki na tag [material-designer](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/material-designer), porém notei que ela foi aprovada posteriormente em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/27941

Longe de mim querer criticar, mas acho que não deveria ter sido aprovado (me perdoem se soar mal o que disse).

Então a duvida é esta, tags com wiki ou fragmento e sem perguntas são deletadas?

Comment: Pior quando o cara diz "o designer do meu site é muito bonito" e a gente fica na dúvida da intenção do comentário. /s

Comment: @Bacco fui "correndo" conferir se eu tinha copiado o texto dele do fragmento/wiki, mas felizmente editei. Ufa não paguei mico... rs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se não tem pergunta a tag é deletada.

Quanto ao wiki, mais ou menos. Eles vão parar numa lista à qual só os moderadores têm acesso. É uma lista de todos os tag wikis órfãos desde o início do site, e que não diz o nome da tag à qual o texto pertencia, nem se ele era o texto principal ou o fragmento. Ou seja, em caso de emergência, o conteúdo está lá, mas a organização dificulta muito encontrá-lo.